# Prevent Empty Database Path using Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any way I can prevent the database to insert values with empty(null) string.

For Eg.

```
/path/to/certainString/value
```

As in the above path, somehow `if certainString = ""` then the database stores value without a proper child

```
-Root
--Key1
---value1  
---value2
---value3
   ...
```

So if Key is empty, then it inserts values something like below

```
-Root
--value1  
--value2
--value3

--Key1
---value1  
---value2
---value3
   ...
```

Is there anyway I can prevent such condition at all paths using **Database Security Rules**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big distinction between a `null` value and an empty string in the Firebase Realtime Database. Firebase *can* store an empty string, but it **cannot** store a `null` value. Trying to store `null` in a path effectively deletes that path from the database. Since the two cases are treated different by Firebase, you'll need to handle them separately in your rules too.

You can prevent a user from storing an empty string with this rule:

```
".validate": "data.isString() && data.val().length > 0"
```

Also see the documentation on the [`RuleDataSnapshot.length` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#length).

To prevent the user from writing `null`, you need to prevent the user from deleting the data at the path. While this is possible, you can't do it with a validation rule, as those are not triggered by a delete operation. So to prevent data deletion/null values, we use a write rule:

```
".write": "newData.exists()"
```

Also see the documentation on the [`RuleDataSnapshot.exists()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#exists).

Comment: Thank you for the response, will look forward to it.

Comment: Does `"data.isString() && data.val().length > 0"` works on only path? Because there might be empty values in the database and I need to store some empty values too.

Comment: It applies to the path that you define the rule on, as all rules do. You'll typically implement your rules as low as possible in the tree, to avoid overly broad rules.